# please help me, how to install wordcloud?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C:\Users\NEW>pip install wordcloud
Collecting wordcloud
  Using cached wordcloud-1.7.0.tar.gz (216 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.6.1 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (1.19.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (7.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from wordcloud) (3.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib->wordcloud) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.1->matplotlib->wordcloud) (1.15.0)
Using legacy setup.py install for wordcloud, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: wordcloud
    Running setup.py install for wordcloud ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NEW\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1emybtc\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NEW\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1emybtc\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w10gqvx7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\wordcloud'
         cwd: C:\Users\NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-v1emybtc\wordcloud\
    Complete output (20 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8
    creating build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\color_from_image.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\tokenization.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\wordcloud_cli.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\_version.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\__main__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\stopwords -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    copying wordcloud\DroidSansMono.ttf -> build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud
    UPDATING build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud/_version.py
    set build\lib.win32-3.8\wordcloud/_version.py to '1.7.0'
    running build_ext
    building 'wordcloud.query_integral_image' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\NEW\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1emybtc\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\NEW\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-v1emybtc\\wordcloud\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\NEW\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-w10gqvx7\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\new\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\wordcloud' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Read the error message: `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/`

Answer (score -1):

It seems like C++ is needed, that's the error